# How to get textX model to treat fifth test case as separate line

Tags: python, textx

Sample code that is failing when adding the fifth test line to the input variable. Leave the fifth line out and the model works.

```
from textx import metamodel_from_str

mm = metamodel_from_str('''
File:
    lines+=Line;

Line:
    startwords=Startwords
    dirp=DirPhrase?
    words=Words?
    command=Commands?
;

Startwords: 
    (StartKeywords | Signs)?;

StartKeywords:
    'bag';

Commands:
    ('sleep over'|'walk');

Words:
    words+=Word?;

Word:
    !DirType !Commands ID;

Signs:
    signs+=Sign;

Sign:
    !Commands !StartKeywords Word;

DirPhrase:
    dirtyp=DirType
    dir=Dir
;

DirType:
    'fast';

Dir:
    ('left'|'right')+;

''')

input = '''
bag  sun kiss  sleep over
animal walk
big horse walk
big white cow fast left
little black cow fast right
'''
#little black cow fast right


model = mm.model_from_str(input, debug=False)

l = model.lines[0]
assert l.startwords == 'bag'
assert l.words.words == ['sun', 'kiss']
assert l.command == 'sleep over'

l = model.lines[1]
assert l.startwords.signs == ['animal']
assert l.words == None
assert l.command == 'walk'

l = model.lines[2]
assert l.startwords.signs == ['big', 'horse']
assert l.words == None
assert l.command == 'walk'

l = model.lines[3]
assert l.startwords.signs == ['big', 'white', 'cow']
assert l.words == None
assert l.command == None
assert l.dirp.dirtyp == 'fast'
assert l.dirp.dir == 'left'

if len(model.lines) == 5:
    l = model.lines[4]
    assert l.startwords.signs == ['little', 'black', 'cow']
    assert l.words == None
    assert l.command == None
    assert l.dirp.dirtyp == 'fast'
    assert l.dirp.dir == 'right'
```

What is happening is somehow the fifth input line is getting read into `l.words` during the fourth input line processing. The assert there fails because `l.words` is supposed to be `None`.  I have tried using `[eolterm]` modifier however that created other errors.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue using `[eolterm]` in the following section of code
from this

```
Words:
    words+=Word?;
```

to this

```
Words:
    words+=Word[eolterm];
```

`[eolterm]` does not like the `?` so had to remove that.  With that gone it works like a champ.

Comment: Correct, `eolterm` will change the repetition to match only on a single line. In assignments, the type of assignment specify the repetition. In this case `+=` is saying that RHS is one-or-more match. So no need for `?`. Actually `?` is wrong at this place.

Comment: I had the `?` there because it is possible for there to be no words in some cases.  Have to retest to see if removing it presents a problem.

Comment: If the Word is optional use zero-or-more assignment `*=`.